# how can I edit a python library installed with pip?

Tags: python, pip

I have installed a Python library from the PyPI. However, I want to add some codes inside it and work with it while editing it. How can I do this?

Comment: Directly in the lib files.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all your installed libraries in `YourPythonDirectory\Lib\site-packages`

Answer (score 0):

Import the library in any Editor(say PyCharm). Then, press `Ctrl + Enter`. or else Right Click on Library Name and Select `Go to Definition`. There you will be able to edit that library. Or else edit in `site-packages` in your Explorer.